# Send Grid View Html in Email Asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am working in asp.net and in that i am using grid view and now i want to convert grid view data which is dynamic to the html table so i can send an email.

I have try following code , But it not render grid view Html.

```
 private string GetTemplate(GridView gd)
        {
            StringBuilder emailBody = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(emailBody);
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gd.RenderControl(hw);
            return emailBody.ToString();
        }

 public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
            /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a div to runat=server and get div innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Finally got solution . This issue due to set `EnableViewState=false` ,When I remove this its worked.